# Give Simba ODBC driver or bigrquery access to Google Drive files

Tags: r, google-sheets, odbc, google-bigquery, stata

I am trying to load a BQ table that is based on a Google Spreadsheet into the statistics package Stata. I have tries two routes to accomplish this.

First, I used the Simba ODBC driver for Mac (version 2.1.6), but I get the following error:

```
The ODBC driver reported the following diagnostics
[Simba][BigQuery] (20) Query execution failed: Access Denied: BigQuery BigQuery: No OAuth token with Google Drive scope was found.
SQLSTATE=HY000
```

In my odbc.ini file, I have set RequestGoogleDriveScope=1, and am using user authentication for OAuth Mechanism. I can query this table in BQ Web UI, and I can load other non-GS tables via ODBC.

Second, I thought that maybe I can do this in R instead, bypassing Simba/ODBC:

```
library(bigrquery)
data <- query_exec("SELECT * FROM my_table;", project = "XXXX", useLegacySql = FALSE)
Error: Access Denied: BigQuery BigQuery: No OAuth token with Google Drive scope was found.
```

---

**To summarize, this query works in BQ web UI, and does not work with R (using the API) or Stata (using ODBC). The common denominator is that neither Stata or R have google drive permissions in  https://myaccount.google.com/permissions, whereas the BQ Client Tools has them.** That is my best guess as to where the problem lies. Any suggestions on how to change the OAuth scope would be appreciated.

**Cross-posted [on Statalist](https://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1433222-allow-the-stata-driver-access-to-google-drive-files).**

Answer (score 3):

This is an OAuth2 topic of bigrquery. The app needs access to sheets in general (Google Drive scope) but it didn't request that scope in the authentication process. Developers of bigrquery simply decided not to do that.

This issue was discussed here: https://github.com/r-dbi/bigrquery/issues/132 and it seems it is out of scope for them.

A possible workaround (not tested though):

- create a view (`SELECT * FROM sheet_table`) in a different dataset
- give this view access to the table: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/share-access-views#authorize_the_view_to_access_the_source_dataset
- Then query the view instead of the original table - basically delegating the access problem to this view.

Comment: Is there any way to remedy this in ODBC route?

Comment: It's the same thing basically, because Google always works with OAuth2 - you'd need to configure the driver so it asks for Google Drive scope. Here's a playground for OAAuth2 Google services - maybe this helps you clarify the concept: https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/

Comment: Thanks for explaining this to me, but isn't this what I am doing with the RequestGoogleDriveScope=1 setting in odbc.ini?

Comment: This didn't work for me. Anybody tried this?